# Can getComuptedStyle return undefined for certain property?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a following snippet and I'm wondering can it return undefined for any of the examined properties in any case

```
if(window.getComputedStyle) {
    var computedStyles = window.getComputedStyle(elt, null);
    return { 
        displayStyle: computedStyles['display'], 
        visibilityStyle: computedStyles['visibility'], 
        overflowStyle: computedStyles['overflow'] 
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No CSS property can have a value of `undefined` (the nearest CSS has is `""`). The only properties that object will have which are undefined will be those which do not represent CSS properties supported by the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.